# Find the sum of the cubes of the roots of a biquadratic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Is it possible to find the sum of the cubes of the roots of a biquadratic polynomial in general?

I have tried it several times but am still unable to do it. Please help.

Comment: Without an equation this is indeed impossible.

Comment: for any general poly

Comment: eg if we take the question Find sum of the cubes of the roots of the quadratic equation???

Comment: the ans is simply  -b^4/a^3+3bc/a^2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ax^4+bx^2+c$ our biquadratic polynomial and let $\pm z_1$ and $\pm z_2$ be its four complex roots. Then 
$$z_1^3+(-z_1)^3+z_2^3+(-z_2)^3=0$$